# Angular How to get access to data from service after subscription

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services

this my service

```
getDataDetails(id: any) {
     this.dataDocumment = this.afs.doc('data/' + id);
     return this.data = this.dataDocumment.valueChanges().subscribe(res =>{
       this.data = res;
       console.log(this.data);
     });
   }
```

and this is my component where I wish to fectch the data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.dataD = this.dataService.getDataDetails(this.id);
    console.log(this.dataD);
  }
```

The data in display of the service display well in the console

```
{adresse: "Rue de France #10", bureau: "78", centre: "Lycée Français", cin: "751-02-785-782-002", commune: "Paris", …}
```

but it display this message from my component

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}
```

PS : dataD is type "any"

I correctly do the subscripe in the service whyi is is dsplaying this in my component ?

Comment: you arent returning the res value, also, its better to subscribe in the page that does the initial call, not where the data is returned

Comment: When I do like you say it just return "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

return the observable from the service and subscribe it inside the component.

```
getDataDetails(id: any) {
    this.dataDocumment = this.afs.doc('data/' + id);
    return this.dataDocumment.valueChanges()
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.dataService.getDataDetails(this.id).subscribe(
    res => {
        this.dataD = res;
        console.log(this.dataD);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but now it only return  "undefinide"

Comment: put the console inside subscribe. check the updated one

Comment: from inside the subscription it displays it but how do I acces the data outside of it cause I need to display them in my template

Comment: once data bound to a variable it already bound to the html. just add `{{dataD | json }}`  in template to check.

Comment: I don't really get what you say

Comment: @Geeksan what does `console.log(this.dataD);` display in the console?

Comment: it displays this " {adresse: "Rue de France #10", bureau: "78", centre: "Lycée Français", cin: "751-02-785-782-002", commune: "Paris", …} " . Just after I modified the code and put the console.log(this.dataD) inside of the subcrbe

Comment: Nothing has chabged really I am still at the same point at the beginning